# First webpage design and code, Dreamweaver HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, web, dreamweaver

I have just designed a very quick website home page and as a first time coder I was wondering if someone would look at the design and my code and tell me where they would make improvements or changes or completely change it if necessary!

The design is for personal use only and contains black sections where my personal address is on the website design.

I am open to any suggestions and comments as this is my first time at coding and I would like to know what a more experience person would do better. I have been using Dreamweaver and viewing it on Google Chrome, there is a HTML code and a CSS code, ideally I would like it to be viewable on different browsers.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> Rosy's Jewellery</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Stylesheet.css">

</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="top">
        <!--Background set in CSS-->
    </div><!--  end of top-->

    <div class="menu">
        <h1>Rosy's Jewellery</h1>                   
        <ul id="nav">       
        <li><a href=""> Home            </a></li>
        <li><a href=""> Jewellery       </a></li>
        <li><a href=""> Locations       </a></li>
        <li><a href=""> Contact Us      </a></li>
        <li><a href=""> Reviews         </a></li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
    <!-- end of menu -->


  <div class="main">
        <p> Welcome to Rosy's Jewellery </p>
              <img src="Images/1.png">

              <img src="Images/2.png">

              <img src="Images/3.png">

              <img src="Images/4.png">

              <img src="Images/5.png">

              <img src="Images/6.png">  </div>
<!--close main-->



<div class="footer">
    <ul id="footer">
        <li> <img src="Images/facebook.png" /> 
        <img src="Images/twitter.png" />  </li>
        <li> Twitter Address</li>
        <li> Addres, Address, Address, Address </li>        
        <li> Telephone Number</li>
    </ul>
</div> 
<!--end of footer--> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper        {
            margin:0 auto;
            background-color:#D1CED4;
            }   

.top            {
            background-color:#000000;
            padding-bottom:2.5em;
            }

.menu           {
            background-color:#FFFFFF;
            border-bottom-width:2px;
            border-bottom-color:#000000;
            border-bottom-style: solid;
            position: relative;
            top:-15px;
            text-align:center;
            font-family:Andalus;
            font-size:18px;
            padding-left:1em;
            padding-right:1em;
            overflow:hidden;
            }

.menu h1        {
            float:left;
            color:#999966;
            font-family:andalus;
            font-size:24;
            }


.main           {
            width:65%;
            margin:0 auto;
            background-color:#FFFFFF;
            text-align:center;
            font-family:andalus;
            font-size:24px;
            padding-top:1px;
            }

.footer         {
            text-align:centre;
            background-color:#C8C8C8;
            color:#000000;
            font-family:andalus;
            margin-bottom:-1em;
            }

#footer li      {
            display:inline-block;
            padding-right:8em;
            vertical-align:middle;
            margin-top: -30px;
            }


#nav            {
            padding-top:15px;
            }

#nav a          {
            text-decoration:none;
            }   

#nav a:link     {
            color:black;
            }

#nav a:visited  {
            color:black;
            }

#nav a:hover    {
            color:black;
            }

img             {
            margin:42px;
            }

#nav ul         {
            display:inline-block;
            }


#nav li         {
            display:inline-block;
            margin-right:4.5em;
            padding-right:2.5em;
            }
```

Comment: I cant see whether or not the picture of my deisgn has uploaded? Can anyone see it?

Comment: its there. we can see that

Comment: you have declared html5 doctype but not used any tag of html5.. any specific reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only 3 suggestions:

1. Use `HTML5` tags since you have declared that as DTD.
2. Never style direct a tag like you have given margin to `<img>`. Try giving class to every element.
3. Use maximum classes instead id's in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your requirements. For a personal website I don't think you don't need more than that. Codes are pretty simple and neat. Unless you want authentication and that sort of stuff to get into your site. Simple is beautiful.